# How to enable KnowledgeBase in dialogFlow after creating it automatically

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I have done below via APIs.

1. [Creating the knowledge base](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/how/knowledge-bases#create-kb)
2. [Adding a document to knowledge Base.](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/how/knowledge-bases#create-kd)

Problem I am facing is once job is done via APIs,

**Problem 1:**
Its not enabling the knowledge base, I have to goto dialogFlow dashboard and enable it manually

[image]

**Problem 2:**
Also I have to add response `$knowledge.answer[1]` manually too.

[image]

**Question:**
Can we do this both programatically. so that there is no need to goto dialogFlow dashboard screen and do this manually. :(

What I think above APIs are useless without these both options.

Note: I can paste the code if some one needs. Thank you in Advance

Comment: Strangely, my console does not display enable and disable buttons (just delete and cancel is there). Moreover, the API doc for the knowledge base has only a few methods that do not include your issues.

Comment: @Gray_Rhino yes you are right. In the beginning I thought that agent will be trained automatically upon creating a knowledge base. but this not happened and nothing like that was mentioned in the documentation too. i.e users have to manually train the agent from the dashboard after creating the knowledge base. I mean whats the point to give APIs to users which do the partial task. Can't users only goto dialogFlow and create the knowledge base and train it from there. :-|

Comment: never used the knowledge base but I totally understand your frustration. Since it is in beta version there's a hope that they will add more useful methods to API for stable release.  You can create a feature suggestion in Google Issue Tracker regarding this. I am sure it is a feature that could help many save time.

Comment: I'm facing the very same issue here. Actually, it doesn't matter if it is enabled or not. But the response has to be set. And I can't do it though API. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @DemetrioGuilardi not yet bro, as per answer below by ismail you need to report this in issue_tracker link below. I didn't have done this yet. can you do it and let share the link over here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 'KnowledgeBases' can only be Enable/Disable through UI, it's an one time configure. If that's not applicable, you can set the knowledge bases for each requests as in 2.
2. 'KnowledgeBases' in 'DetectIntent' requests can be set through the [knowledge_base_names[]](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/priv/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1?hl=en#queryparameters) query parameter.

Note that:

- 'KnowledgeBases' are just repositories of documents that you can use in 'DetectIntent', agent assist, etc. They don't have enabled/disabled state.
- What's referenced to as "Enabled/Disabled" in the UI is an agent setting that means 'DetectIntent' uses the 'KnowledgeBases' by default if no knowledge bases are set in the 'DetectIntent request'.

Regarding your comment "What I think above APIs are useless without these both options." I think it's a valid feature request that I highly recommend for you to submit it through [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked. Now detectIntent catch our knowledgebase too. Thank you for the directions. 
I also have created the issue in issue tracker too. https://issuetracker.google.com/203772221